# PHP Sticky form

Tags: php, html

When I input numeric value in Number 1 and Number 2, and press "Add". It does not display the total added value. Please see my coding below. and advice me, what to is the problem, and what can be done.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple Calculator</title>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submitted'])){
        if(is_numeric($_POST['number1']) && is_numeric($_POST['number2'])){
        $add = ($_POST['number1'] + $_POST['number2']);
            echo "Add: ".$_POST['number1']."+".$_POST['number2']."=";
            }
        }



?>
<script type="text/javascript">


</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Simple Calculator</h1>
<form action="simple_calculator.php" method="post">
<p>Number 1: <input type="text" name="number1" size="20" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['number1'])) echo $_POST['number1'];?>"/></p>
<p>Number 2: <input type="text" name="number2" size="20" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['number2'])) echo $_POST['number2'];?>"/></p>

          <input type="button" name="add" value="Add" />
          <input type="button" name="minus" value="Minus" />
          <input type="button" name="multiply" value="Multiply" />
          <input type="button" name="divide" value="Divide" />
          <input type="reset" name="rest" value="Reset" />
          <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You are echoing the result data into the `<head>`, so it will not be displayed.
2. You forgot to echo `$add`.
3. Your `<input>`s are of type `button` and not `submit`, so the form will not be submitted to the server.
4. Because you are echoing the previously entered values into the form, `<input type="reset">` will probably not do what you want/expect it to do. I think it would be better to implement this as another `submit`.
5. Because this form affects only what the next page displays and does not make a permanent change to the server, you should use the `GET` method and not `POST`.

Try this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Calculator</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Simple Calculator</h1>
    <form action="simple_calculator.php" method="get">
      <p>Number 1: <input type="text" name="number1" size="20" value="<?php if (isset($_GET['number1']) && !isset($_GET['reset'])) echo $_GET['number1'];?>"/></p>
      <p>Number 2: <input type="text" name="number2" size="20" value="<?php if (isset($_GET['number2']) && !isset($_GET['reset'])) echo $_GET['number2'];?>"/></p>
      <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add" />
      <input type="submit" name="minus" value="Minus" />
      <input type="submit" name="multiply" value="Multiply" />
      <input type="submit" name="divide" value="Divide" />
      <input type="submit" name="reset" value="Reset" />
      <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1" />
    </form>
    <?php

        if (isset($_GET['submitted']) && !isset($_GET['reset'])) {

            echo "<div>";

            if (is_numeric($_GET['number1']) && is_numeric($_GET['number2'])) {

                if (isset($_GET['add'])) {

                    $result = $_GET['number1'] + $_GET['number2'];
                    echo "Add: ".$_GET['number1']." + ".$_GET['number2']." = ".$result;

                } else if (isset($_GET['minus'])) {

                    $result = $_GET['number1'] - $_GET['number2'];
                    echo "Minus: ".$_GET['number1']." - ".$_GET['number2']." = ".$result;

                } else if (isset($_GET['multiply'])) {

                    $result = $_GET['number1'] * $_GET['number2'];
                    echo "Multiply: ".$_GET['number1']." * ".$_GET['number2']." = ".$result;

                } else if (isset($_GET['divide'])) {

                    $result = $_GET['number1'] / $_GET['number2'];
                    echo "Divide: ".$_GET['number1']." / ".$_GET['number2']." = ".$result;

                }

            } else {

                echo "Invalid input";

            }

            echo "</div>";

        }

    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks alot.. but the same problem, it does not display

Comment: @MushfiqurRahman It may be because I changed the value of the `action` for the form for testing on my server - I have just edited/fixed, try version above.

Comment: ya it works with the get method in the demo... BUt my teacher asked me to do it with the "post" method.. I am banging my head, and trying to figure out why it does not display. with this simple work I am stuck for 3 hours. But u r a real help thanks. But can you suggest me any way how to display this using post :-)

Comment: @MushfiqurRahman The same code works via POST simply by changing `method="get"` to `method="post"` and `$_GET` to `$_POST`. It doesn;t work on codepad because of the nature of the way that codepad works, but it certainly works on my local dev server...

Answer (score 0):

The solution of DaveRandom works fine if you change this

```
action="simple_calculator.php"
```

by

```
action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"
```